# Multiple Event on a map Marker

Tags: javascript, dom-events, openlayers-3, markers

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
}


#selection-map {
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.selection-title {
    height: 15%;
    width: 15%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #DA1A21;
    font-size: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    color: #DA1A21;
}

.selection-form {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.selection-form input {
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SouthWest Airport Map</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/ol3/ol.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol3.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="selection-map" class="map">
      <h2 class="selection-title">Airports Selected</h2>
      <form class="selection-form" method="post" action="traitement.php">
        <p><input type="text" id="input-airports" placeholder="Click a marker" /></p>
        <p>For Selecting Multiple Airpots, please press Shift and select all the markers that you need</p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="../common/lib/reqwest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ol3/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="ol3.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I implemented a map with markers pointing to airports, and when I click on a marker the name of the airport appears in a field. (All data included in a GEOJson external file). I just have a last problem that I can't resolve :

I can only select one marker at a time, and i want to be able to select multiples Markers, and make all the name appears in the field. I think that my problem are that I need to change the calling my features, but i don't know what to write instead. I already tried to change my function from "forEachFeatureAtPixel" to "forFeatureAtPixel" or things like that, but every time I break my map.

I'm a beginner in Javascript :/ Here is my JS code

```js
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: '//localhost/osgis-ol3-leaflet-master/ol3/data.geojson'
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 10,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'green'
      })
    })
  })
});
var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
    url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.json',
    crossOrigin: ''
  })
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
 view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 3
    })
});

var input = document.getElementById('id-airports');

var select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(select_interaction);

select_interaction.on('select', function(evt) {
  var features = select_interaction.getFeatures();
  var value = '';
  features.forEach(function(feature){
    // change this to your own needs
    value += feature.get('name') + ', ';
  });
  
  input.value = value;
});

map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (e.dragging) return;
  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent));
  map.getTarget().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/vtfuqbuj/)) — To select multiple use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click

You will remove that another approach:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
        evt.pixel, function(ft, l) { return ft; });
  if (feature) ...
});
```

And use `ol.interaction.Select`, see bellow.

---

There's a select interaction that you can add to your map with a lot of options, see [`ol.interaction.Select`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html). You can set, for instance some conditions:

```
// only select with Mouse Hover
var select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
   condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});
```

Another condition:

```
// only select with Alt key + Click
var select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: function(mapBrowserEvent) {
    return ol.events.condition.click(mapBrowserEvent) &&
      ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly(mapBrowserEvent);
    }
});
```

In your case, putting all together would be something like:

```
var select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(select_interaction);

// add a listener to know when features are selected
select_interaction.on('select', function(evt) {
  var features = select_interaction.getFeatures();
  features.forEach(function(feature){
    // change this to your own needs
    input.value += feature.get('name') + ', ';
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I can still click on only one marker at a time, and the name doesn't appear in the field anymore. i just put what i tried to do in my post

Comment: sorry but it's not working again, i don't why, i changed the get('desc') by name but still nothing, i don't have any error simply nothing seems to happen. Thanks for the answer :/ i updated my code in my answer

Comment: Did you remove `map.on('click', function(evt) {` block code?

Comment: In your updated question you have the first two blocks of code conflicting (and repeated).

Comment: ok, i just updated it, with the entire JS file just to be sure :s

Comment: Which OL are you using? This `ol.source.GeoJSON` was removed a long time ago. Use always the latest version and look at my fiddle, it uses `ol.source.Vector`.

Comment: ok, i tried to take your code, as you post it in the fiddle, just by changing the tile cause i need an openstreet map and i changed the view and Geoson source. but now all my map is broken and i have no error in my console. :/

Comment: *Pay attention on the details!* You're not ***adding*** `vectorLayer` to the map.

Comment: This question is already solved (and is extending beyond its scope) as you can see in the fiddle. I'll let you find out what is missing in your code.

Comment: I hope i will find thks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. It should be very simple. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if this is the case.

Comment: Sorry i'm coming back, because i tried to find my error, but i didn't sucess. I took your code, and take it back step by step, but i don't find what i'm missing. the only thing that i changed is the url of my geojson source, the id of my field and the ol view. :S code updated

Comment: Thank u a lot :) ok i just posted my html and css ( u have everything ), i changed the url still nothing :s

Comment: Which OL version are you using? Try to change `src="lib/ol3/ol.js"` to `src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.16.0/ol.js"`

Comment: Everything is working perfectly now by changing the ol version. Thank you a lot for your help ! :D

Comment: Glad to hear! Thanks God! Have a great day.